# How to pass contenteditable text to value attribute in django html file

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have tried finding resource but couldn't get any.

I have a html file in templates folder in my django app as

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<li contenteditable = "TRUE" >{{comment.text}}
<form contenteditable = "FALSE"  action = "{% url 'clickedaccept' %}" method = "POST">
{% csrf_token %}
               <input type = "hidden" name = "acceptedvalue" value = "{{comment.id}}">

             <input type = "hidden" name = "selected_option" value = "{{selected_option}}">

            <input type = "hidden" name = "selected_autocomplete" value = "{{selected_autocomplete}}">

              <input type = "submit" value = "Accept" id = "{{comment.id}}" >
      </form>
{% endfor %}
</li>
```

Here the comment.text is extracted from model and is editable. User can edit the text value. There is a form with post method. I want to send the value of content editable text in value attribute of hidden input. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Post your django's model code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, assuming your model has a Charfield called 'selected_option'.

forms.py

```
class PracticeForm(forms.Form):

    selected_value = forms.CharField(max_length=202, required=True)
    selected_option = forms.CharField(max_length=202, required=True)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PracticeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            foo1 = form.cleaned_data.get("selected_value")
            foo2 = form.cleaned_data.get("selected_option")
```

html

```
<form contenteditable = "FALSE"  action = "{% url 'clickedaccept' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST">
{% csrf_token %}
           <input type = "hidden" name = "selected_value" value = "{{comment.id}}">
         <input type = "hidden" name = "selected_option" value = "{{selected_option}}">
              <button type = "submit">Click this to submit</button>
      </form>
```